# How to get auth token in Login action. MVC5

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I've ASP.NET MVC5 project with standard auth process.

After calling `/Account/Login` I've got response with new cookie `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` with auth token. The question is how to get this token in Login action, **right after it's generated**?

My only idea is to try obtain it from response's cookie but it doesn't work:

```
// ... somwhere in login action
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
// <-- How to obtain auth token here? Code below don't work

var token = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Response.Cookies[".AspNet.ApplicationCookie"];
```

.. but this is not even compiling.

Comment: how did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.Cookies[".AspNet.ApplicationCookie"]
```

Not sure if there is a leading period "." though, also try:

```
Request.Cookies["AspNet.ApplicationCookie"]
```

Comment: Not working. Server side generates token and sends it to client via response.cookie in order to create cookie in client side. Your code will work in the next request but I want the token right after it's generated. Not in the next request.

Comment: @DamianDrygiel - okay I see, this wasn't clear in your question. What do you need the token for though?

Answer (score 0):

On callback action from OAuth you could use Request.Cookies[".AspNet.ExternalCookie"]

Answer (score -1):

I believe you may be confusing Request and Response.  Response is what you send TO the client - so you never want to read a cookie from there.  Instead, read the cookie from the Request object.

If you "read" from the Response object and the cookie doesn't' already exist in it, it will simply create a NEW cookie of that name - with no value!

Comment: I'm not confusing request and response. You misunderstood my question. I need just generated token before server sends response to the client.